# ほか usage clarification

Tags: particles, word-usage

I was reading this article at [NHK](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20200510/k10012424141000.html?utm_int=all_side_ranking-social_005), and in it there is a sentence that reads:

> 感染者の中には、今月２日ではなく別の日にこのナイトクラブを訪れた人がいた**ほか**、ソウル以外の地方から訪れた人もいたということです。

Which I think I understand the main point of to mean:

> [The report said] Of the infected people, there are people who visited that night club on a different day from the 2nd, and people who visited from a region outside of Seoul.

I am however, not sure how to interpret the **ほか** part of this sentence. I usually see it as a の adjective used to describe "other" as in 他の人. But here it seems to serve a more grammatical/particle-like purpose.

What is the usage of this word here? I am also wondering if this is more frequent in newspaper writing vs. less formal conversations.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/when-to-use-%e4%bb%96-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%ae-or-%e4%bb%96-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%ab